# find file, copy but with different name

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rename, file-copy

I have files with random numbers in /home/user/files folder (every 4 days I have new ones).
for example:

```
john20
john25
john40
tom12
tom32
simon2
simon8
simon53
```

I want to take only last modified files (the newest) and copy them to different location (/home/user/fixed) without that numbers in file name.

I know how to filter and copy that using find command but I don't know how copy all of them without that numbers.

```
find $files_are_here -maxdepth 1 -mtime -2 -type f -exec cp {} $new_path \;
```

This will copy all of the files modified in the last 2 days to the new path but with original name. In my case:

```
john40
tom32
simon53
```

but I would like to have only john, tom and simon inside that folder. So after I run my script again they will be replaced by the newest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is hopefully self explanatory

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime -2 -type f  -exec bash -c 'name=${1##*/}; cp  "$name" /some/other/dir/${name%%[0-9]*}' _ {} \;
```

Comment: This assumes that you have `cd`’ed into the directory where the existing files are, and it breaks if you take out the `-maxdepth 1`. You can fix both of these by changing `cp "$name" …` to `cp "$1" …`

Comment: P.S. The word is “explanatory”.

Comment: @G-Man it indeed is 'explanatory'. I stand corrected. `find` when no path specified, assumes the `$(PWD)`. So since I was not sure where OP's files were located I assumed the current dir. Then of course the command changes slightly. `names${1##*/}` would no longer be necessary. Just a way to show how `PE (Parameter Expansion)` works

Comment: Yes, I know `find` defaults to a path of `.`. But we ***do*** know where the OP’s files are located – they’re in `$files_are_here`. … … … … I don’t understand what you mean by “`names=${1##*/}` would no longer be necessary” – you still need it to have a basename to strip the digits from, in `${name%%[0-9]*}`.

Comment: If we used "$1" as you suggested, then we could use "${1%%[0-9]*}" as being the positional parameter without defining a variable.

Comment: Well, as I said, you answer assumes that you have `cd`’ed into the directory where the existing files are. If you said `find srcdir -maxdepth 1 -mtime -2 -type f -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" /some/other/dir/${1%%[0-9]*}' _ {} \;`, it would try to copy `srcdir/john20` to `/some/other/dir/srcdir/john` (which is wrong). You need a step to extract `john20` from `srcdir/john20`. It only works when you leave off the search directory (letting it default to `.`, not `$(PWD)`) because `/some/other/dir/./john` is equivalent to `/some/other/dir/john`.

Comment: This copies files modified in the last two days. The question was about copying the latest file in each set.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful and it works now for me. I have one more question. How to deal with different names e.g. john-20.dmp? it is possible to have at the end file as a john.dmp?

Answer (score 1):

```
find -mtime -2 \
     -maxdepth 1 \
    \! -type d \
    \( -name 'simon*' \
    -o -name 'tom*' \
    -o -name 'john*' \
    \) | tar -T - \
     --xform='s/[0-9]*$//' \
     -cf - | tar -C ./path/to/destination --keep-newer-files -xf -
```

I think that will do it - it appears to work for me. So long as the `simon`, `tom`, and `john` files are intended to be overwritten once every two days - I believe this should do it. Either that or it is very close. Oh, but, it does require GNU `tar` - and probably GNU `find` as well, though I'm not sure about the latter. I didn't check too hard on those because the majority of those were your own options.